# Level hardwood floor that was covered by baseboard

Tags: flooring, level

I recently removed my baseboard to be able to put the free standing wardrobe close to the wall.
I noticed that the approximately 1 inch of floor where the baseboard was sitting on is a little higher than the rest of the room - don't know why. Maybe it was an old floor?
I need to level the floor, or even remove it, so the wardrobe sits straight on the floor.

[image]

[image]

What would you recommend? Using a rotary tool with a sanding drum would do it?

This "uncovered" floor is maybe 1/6 inch higher than the rest of the room.
A little less than 1 inch wide (baseboard depth) and 60 inches long.
Ideally I should not remove it, because there will be a gap.

Thanks!

Comment: From the picture it's hard to tell.  Is it an additional layer of material on top of the wood or does it look like the floors were refinished at some point and they just couldn't sand that close to the wall (so it's thicker and all one piece)?

Comment: I'm having trouble identifying the issue from the description and picture. Maybe an arrow or two showing exactly what you're talking about would help.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I included a new picture, hope it helps!

Comment: @FreeMan I included a new picture, hope it helps!

Comment: I think the new picture helps. If I understand, that piece pointed to by all the red arrows sticks out beyond the plaster, such that if you put a square on the floor and push it toward the wall, it will hit that piece _before_ the blade of the square touches the plaster. If that's the case, I'd agree with [isherwood's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/160857/34147) - cut out a small section of that piece of wood.

Comment: When you remove that piece, there _will_ be a bit of a gap (though you could chisel _down_ to remove only the portion that sticks out beyond the wall), however, it will be inconsequential since it will be hidden by the wardrobe. When you remove that, you'll reinstall the baseboard which will also hide the gap. It's what I've heard framing carpenters call "trim to fit". i.e. once the trim is in place, everything "fits".

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a cut using whatever small saw you have on hand--keyhole, reciprocating, oscillating--at each side of the opening just down to floor level.
2. Use a chisel or other sharp tool to split the grain at floor level, shaving off a thin strip.

```
_________ ___________________ ____________ <-- top of protruding board 
_________|___________________|____________ <-- floor level
               ^-- chisel here
         ^-- vertical cuts --^
```

Alternatively, install some plastic feet on the front of your wardrobe and forget about it.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a little better this cut? Cut horizontally ou vertically? Thank you!

Comment: "Down to floor level" implies vertically. "At floor level" would've meant horizontally. :)

Comment: based on the new pictures, I think the cutting method is the right approach. I don't think the feet will work, OP seems to want the front to be flush with the floor (here's hoping the floor is perfectly level...)

Comment: Flush with =/= tight to. https://www.carpentry-tips-and-tricks.com/Carpentry-Terms.html#F

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's "old floor", I think that because you removed the wallboard, you are into the interior stud wall structure and that is the top surface of the bottom plate of your wall. I like the idea of just putting some little feet or pads on your wardrobe to raise it up over that lip.

Comment: But then there will be a gap accumulating dust underneath the wardrobe. If I fix this little higher floor, then it will be sitting on the floor correctly.

Comment: The bottom plate is the larger board with the cut mark on it.